# Async stack equivalent of TPL Dataflow BufferBlock<T>

Tags: c#, .net, concurrency, async-await, tpl-dataflow

`BufferBlock<T>` is a very nice async interface to a queue.

What I'm looking for is something like that but for a LIFO stack.  I'm looking for equivalent functionality of `BlockingCollection` when passed a `ConcurrentStack` but instead of blocking a thread on Take and Add, I want to have `TakeAsync` and `AddAsync`.  This is basically what `BufferBlock<T>` gives me but it's a FIFO queue, and I need a LIFO stack.

I am looking for a lock free version of an async stack.  I don't care if it fits in nicely with dataflow or not, I was just using `BufferBlock` as an example.  I'm not planning on using this in conjunction with dataflow.

Answer (score 4):

[`TPL Dataflow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of course doesn't support such functionality, otherwise it wouldn't have a "flow".

What you can do is use Stephen Cleary's [`AsyncCollection`](http://nitoasyncex.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=AsyncCollection). It's an async wrapper around any [`IProducerConsumerCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287147%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which in your case could be [`ConcurrentStack`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267331%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
var stack = new ConcurrentStack<int>();
var asyncStack = new AsyncCollection<int>(stack);

await asyncStack.AddAsync(4);
await asyncStack.AddAsync(6);

int top = await asyncStack.TakeAsync();
```

Comment: Yes I'm aware TPL dataflow does not have this functionality, that's why I asked the question.  Stephen Cleary's AsyncCollection has many lock's and other such less efficient techniques.  I'm looking for a lock free version.  I'll update the question to include that detail.

Comment: @AaronStainback I haven't seen any locks in AsyncCollection, unless you count AsyncLock and you really shouldn't. I highly doubt you can find a more efficient solution. But if you think you can improve it, you're always welcome to.

Comment: There are locks in the internals of my async primitives. But those are almost always uncontended. When you get into async coordination, the async/task semantics "lift" the synchronization right into user-space code. So, locks are only used for protecting internal state, not for coordination (very similar to [how locks are used internally by `BufferBlock<T>`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/12/05/10244302.aspx)). Due to this "lifting" and the spin+block semantics of `lock`, lock-free async coordination primitives are unnecessary IMO.